# How do I solve "Application is waiting for the debugger to attach" error?

Tags: java, android, debugging, error-handling, bluestacks

I am able to run the app but cannot debug it using my BlueStacks emulator on android studio. Every time I try to debug, an error saying the following pops up!

[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7Ydg.png)

Please help me fix it. Thank you.

Comment: This is not an error. If you wait long enough, the debugger should attach to your device and then run your app.

Comment: Nothing is happening man. I have been waiting since forever :(